# Round off an apex variable upto two decimal places

Tags: visualforce, apex-variable, rounding

I have apex variable in my visualforce page, which is calculated as below -

```
<apex:variable var="cntFinal" value="{!IF(cntVar1==0,0,(cntVar2+cntVar3)*100/cntVar1)}"/>
```

Now, I want to set this `cntFinal` value up to two decimal places. For example,
if the value is 0.23769, I want to show 0.24.
This conversion have to be as Number, not as a string(using `<apex:outputText>` will convert it to text). As I will be using this to calculate other values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping everything in visualforce here, there is a function to do precisely what you're looking for, `ROUND`.

It appears about half-way down the documentation page on [visualforce functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)

> **ROUND**
>   Returns the nearest number to a number you specify, constraining the new number by a specified number of digits.
>   **ROUND(number, num_digits)** and replace number with the field or expression you want rounded; replace num_digits with the number of decimal places you want to consider when rounding.

An example of usage:

```html
<!-- 20/3 = 6.6666... rounding to 2 decimal places should result in 6.67 -->
<apex:variable var="myVar" value="{!ROUND(20/3, 2)}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `setScale()` method to round a decimal

```
Decimal no = 1.23345;
Decimal result = no.setScale(2);
system.debug(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to write JS thing you can do it, only using apex tags see below working examples.

I think ROUND is the best function for using round off the decimal value.
just like

```
<apex:outputText value="{!ROUND(Quote.Discount, 2)}" /><!--2 is your decimal places -->
<apex:variable var="cntFinal" value="{!ROUND(Quote.Discount, 2)}"/><!--here also 2 is your decimal places -->
```

you could use it at any apex tag with value.